# I'm trying to find a more efficient approach for selecting a certain scrambled sequence from a large library

Tags: python, permutation, python-itertools

I'm using Python for a project, and for part of that project, I need to get a scrambled permutation of a library of strings that I feed into the method. I want to get a replicable result out, so I am currently using the permutation method of the itertools library and then looping through it until I reach a certain permutation. However, looping through a bunch of times is obviously not the best for time, especially with scrambles with more elements (20+). Is there anyone who has worked with itertools before who can tell me how to find the scramble faster, or is there someone who can give me a better method for scrambling?

Code Below VVV

```
    import itertools
from itertools import permutations
def genkey(library, toget):
    scrambled = permutations(library)
    iternum = 0
    for fin in scrambled:
        if iternum == toget:
            return(list(fin))
        else:
            iternum += 1
    print('Permutation out of range')
    return
```

My main aim is just to find a way that I can get a replicable scramble that is seemingly random but can be replicated based on an int that I fed in. I'm open to any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you can use the `random` module:

```
import random

random.seed(1)    # Choose another number here if you want a different outcome
scrambled = random.sample(library, k=len(library))
```

Everytime this is run with the same parameter to `seed()` you should get the same value for `scrambled`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a look                     Edit: It worked, thanks again